# What is the fastest way of deleting old data from MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with a lot of data with column "time created". In this database there are more than 12 000 000 of rows created during last 3 years. I need to delete data older than 3 month by chunks, 1000 at once. Is it better to start from oldest data or from newest data ?

I do this through flexible search . It is the safest method since we use our own ORM in our platform and along with these data other data that have relation would be deleted. I can't copy them all. I can't do in partitioning. Only one question: how it would be faster ? Is mysql somehow optimised for such queries ?

Comment: if you're able to do it offline, I'd suggest just copying data less than 3 months old into a new table, drop the old one and rename the new one. Going forward, I'd suggest looking at partitioning the data into segments by date, so you can simply drop a partition rather than delete individual rows.

Comment: Please add table definitions so we can see indexes. Define a lot and guestimate data distribution 11yr 9 months vs 3 months. I hope you have no FKs on data to be removed..

Comment: *Is it better to start from oldest data or from newest data ?* It is better to delete data without any sorting, with only date checking, until rows which matches "too old" condition absence. PS. Do not use NOW() in the condition, use CURRENT_DATE only. PPS. For further clearing process simplifying you may think about partitioning by date - this allows remove old rows with simple old partition dropping.

Comment: I do this through flexible search . It is the safest method since we use our own ORM in our platform and along with these data other data that have relation would be deleted. I can't copy them all. I can't do in partitioning. 
Only one question: how it would be faster ? Is mysql somehow optimised for such queries ?

Comment: If you want to perform the deletion via your ORM instruments only then it makes no sense to ask about any optimization on the MySQL level. It will perform strictly the query which your ORM will send to it. *Only one question: how it would be faster ?* In your case - no difference.

Comment: 20 000 carts , ASC = 7.03 min DESC = 5.57 locally

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not in the order of deletion, but in how you locate the rows to delete.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see what `INDEXes` are available and advise further.

In the long run, you should switch to `PARITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` and have, say, one month per partition.  Then `DROP PARTITION` is very fast.

More discussion of both, plus other techniques:

[*Deletion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)
[*Partition*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

`OFFSET` is a very inefficient.

Comment: "SELECT {" + CartModel.PK + "} FROM {" + CartModel._TYPECODE + "} WHERE {" + CartModel.MODIFIEDTIME + "} <= ?modifiedBefore AND {" + CartModel.SITE + "} = ?site " + NOT_SAVED_CART_CLAUSE + " ORDER BY {" + CartModel.MODIFIEDTIME + "} DESC LIMIT ";


Is it better tu use "} DESC LIMIT" or "} ASC LIMIT" ?

Comment: @RomanLototskyi - I see the word `LIMIT` 3 times; please fix.

Comment: after "Is it better to use" is just my comment .